# GNUPG : GPG can't open 'c:\folder1' no such directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, gnupg

Hi I'm hitting an issue when using GNUPG to encrypt a file.
Below is the command i'm using ,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG>gpg --recipient testkey --multifile --encrypt "C:\ScriptTest\EncryptFile\1.txt"
gpg: can't open `C:\ScriptTest\EncryptFile\1.txt': No such file or directory
gpg: encryption of `C:\ScriptTest\EncryptFile\1.txt' failed: file open error

C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG>gpg --recipient testkey --multifile --encrypt "C:\Script\EncryptFile\1.txt"
File `C:\Script\EncryptFile\1.txt.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N) n
Enter new filename: a
gpg: can't create `a': Permission denied
gpg: encryption of `C:\Script\EncryptFile\1.txt' failed: file create error
```

It's showing No such file or directory when i try to encrypt a file.
I've set the bin directory in 'View Advanced System Settings' and still the same.Is there something else I should be looking at? 
My version is gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.21

Comment: Are you sure that you have the appropriate permissions on the files and/or directories?

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I found the fix for this issue , all I needed to do was to set this path *C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG* on **View Advanced System Settings**.
Now everything is working fine. :)

Thank you for your comments @Compo & @Mofi